# Ionic: Managing Multiple iOS Builds

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app I'm using to build multiple versions of the same app for different organizations. A gulp script swaps out all the assets/config.xml for me. This has worked pretty well for android, as I have the apks outputted into separate folders when they're signed, but I'm not sure how to do the same with iOS.

Is there a way to specify the output path of the project so I can keep all the project settings separate? I'd hate to have to change the certificates, provisioning profile, etc. every time I build an app for a different org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Git and branches for this type of version management.

A master branch where you do all generic development which all apps will take advantage of.

A branch for each organisation. Whenever you make specific changes for an organisation, checkout their branch, merge master into it (to get up to date with generic changes) and then make the specific changes.

There are some great git guides via github: https://guides.github.com/