# Ionic build same app with different styles

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, build

i just finished my app with ionic, cordova and angular.
Now i want to make the same app look different but also want to keep the current style - only colors and some images, at one html page the html code also changed - but the ts files are all the same.

Now i want to manage "both" apps in the same project and just get the specific styled app via the build process.
Like switching the scss and html files via the build process.

Is there any functionality or some idea how i can achieve this?

Important is, that i also have diverent images - and therefore i need more then just a theme switch. Otherwise if i create more and more different styled apps with the same logic and only theme switching the app size would grow a lot cause it always contains all the images and styles for all apps.

Edit: I found the solution to make relative paths (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46899829/4082299)
so does anybody know if i can change the imports and the component templateUrl to a dynamic path which will be set in build process - so the path of the html and scss file is app specific - will there always ONLY the app specific content in the app or everything?

Comment: The single answer on this question is a possible solution to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546180/ionic-managing-multiple-ios-builds

Comment: @Elemental its a while. i did a solution where i added a new folder "distributions" and here i had all files (resources) for the different styles in seperat folders. then i added a script in the cordova routine which will copy/override the files when i build dthe app with a specific distribution parameter